# Rotating Emulator Window while replaying Location Routes

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-gps, autorotate, android-automotive

ive noticed that the window of my Android Emulator will rotate while im replaying a route from the Emulator Menu.

- The window rotation matches the bearing of the GPS signal.
- Ive confirmed this is happening with all of the emulators that are custom built, but not with those in Android Studio

[Emulator with Route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zarfx.png)

How do i keep this from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. The Android Studio Emulator I was using (34.x.x) came from an old Canary Version of my Android Studio.

Reverting to Emulator version 31.3.13 fixed the issue! Here is a description on how to downgrade: [Emulator archive](https://developer.android.com/studio/emulator_archive)